# How can I evaluate the code in function of a boolean column in a data table in R?

Tags: r, data.table

I have a new issue with my code, regarding to the first version in https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56680932/edit

I've realized that my output was wrong, because I always want to save in the column "new" the "category" value whose "priority" value is smaller.

Here is the code updated:

```r
priority <- c(3,2,1,4,5,6,7)
category <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g")
library(data.table)
data.dt <- data.table(priority,category)

data.dt$new <- NA
data.dt$new2 <- NA
data.dt$rest <- NA

for (i in 2:nrow(data.dt)){
  if(data.dt$priority[i]<=ifelse(is.na(data.dt$new[i-1]),data.dt$priority[i-1],data.dt$new[i-1])){
    data.dt$new[[i]] <- data.dt$priority[i]
    data.dt$new2[[i]] <- data.dt$category[i]
    data.dt$rest[[i]]<- toString(data.dt$category[1:(i-1)])
    }
  else{
    data.dt$new[[i]] <- data.dt$new[i-1]
    data.dt$new2[[i]] <- data.dt$new2[i-1]
    data.dt$rest[[i]] <- toString(data.dt$category[1:i])
  }
}
```

And its output:

```r
> data.dt
   priority category new new2                rest
1:        3        a  NA <NA>                <NA>
2:        2        b   2    b                   a
3:        1        c   1    c                a, b
4:        4        d   1    c          a, b, c, d
5:        5        e   1    c       a, b, c, d, e
6:        6        f   1    c    a, b, c, d, e, f
7:        7        g   1    c a, b, c, d, e, f, g
```

If I add @jay.sf 's code to drop the value of "new2" from "rest":

```r
priority <- c(3,2,1,4,5,6,7)
category <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g")
library(data.table)
data.dt <- data.table(priority,category)

data.dt$new <- NA
data.dt$new2 <- NA
data.dt$rest <- NA

for (i in 2:nrow(data.dt)){
  if(data.dt$priority[i]<=ifelse(is.na(data.dt$new[i-1]),data.dt$priority[i-1],data.dt$new[i-1])){
    data.dt$new[[i]] <- data.dt$priority[i]
    data.dt$new2[[i]] <- data.dt$category[i]
    #data.dt$rest[[i]]<- toString(data.dt$category[1:(i-1)])
    }
  else{
    data.dt$new[[i]] <- data.dt$new[i-1]
    data.dt$new2[[i]] <- data.dt$new2[i-1]
    #data.dt$rest[[i]] <- toString(data.dt$category[1:i])
  }
}

sc <- Map(function(x) c(data.dt$category[seq(x)]), seq(nrow(data.dt)))
data.dt$rest <- unlist(c(NA, Map(function(x, y) 
  toString(x[is.na(match(x, y))]), sc, data.dt$new2)[-1]))
```

The output is:

```r
> data.dt
   priority category new new2             rest
1:        3        a  NA <NA>             <NA>
2:        2        b   2    b                a
3:        1        c   1    c             a, b
4:        4        d   1    c          a, b, d
5:        5        e   1    c       a, b, d, e
6:        6        f   1    c    a, b, d, e, f
7:        7        g   1    c a, b, d, e, f, g
```

I know that it isn't the optimal way to do it, but is working. Can you show me if there is a more proper way to do it?

On the other hand, I want to make this comparison depending on another column I'm going to add to the data table. Here is the example:

```r
> data.dt
   overlap priority category new new2             rest
1:       0        3        a  NA <NA>             <NA>
2:       1        2        b   2    b                a
3:       1        1        c   1    c             a, b
4:       1        4        d   1    c          a, b, d
5:       0        5        e   NA   NA              NA
6:       1        6        f   1    e                f
7:      NA        7        g   1    e                f,g
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what exactly you want. When you say the `new` column should show the `category` that has a smaller `priority` value...in most cases there are multiple smaller values but that isn't captured in the way that you say works. What is the logic that explains what is in `new` and `new2`?

Comment: Hi @Megan, let's think we have a for loop that iterates over the table(1st row, 2nd...). Here we compare the "priority" column value in i iteration with the value in i-1 iteration. Then we save the smaller value of them on "new[i]" and its corresponding value of "category" column in "new2[i]". The other value of "category" column which is not being saved in "new" column is being acumulated in "rest" column, as you see in the example. Now cames the "overlap" column, which indicates if the comparison is made, see row 5 "overlap" is 0 and there isn't comparison in this iteration. Is it clear?